# React Native Maps in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, android-mapview, api-key, react-native-maps

I know we need to add an API key to view a Google map
Then, if react-native-maps is integrated with Expo and we use MapView just by importing from React-native.
So where to add the API key in native Map Expo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add keys to in your `app.json`, here's the expo guide you look at [expo guide](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploying-to-a-standalone-app-on-android)

> In app.json, copy the API key from android.config.googleSignIn to android.config.googleMaps.apiKey

It should look like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY_HERE"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY_HERE"
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot fayeed! I also did not read the docs properly.

Comment: I understand this is what the Expo docs say but how safe is it?